Serializar objeto
soy nuevo con el tema de programación, estoy trabajando con .net core v8 y estoy tratando de consumir un API en el que me envían un algo como lo siguiente:
[
  {
      "List<Obj_A>": [
          {
              "Key1": "value",
              "Key2": "value"
          },
          {
              "Key1": "value",
              "Key2": "value"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "List<Obj_B>": [
          {
              "Key3": "value",
              "Key4": "value"
          },
          {
              "Key3": "value",
              "Key4": "value"
          }
      ]
  },
  {
      "List<Obj_C>": [
          {
              "Key3": "value",
              "Key4": "value"
          },
          {
              "Key3": "value",
              "Key4": "value"
          }
      ]
  }
]

Básicamente estoy recibiendo varias listas de objetos, pero las listas son de objetos distintos (lista de obj_A, obj_B, Obj_C). cual es la forma que debe tener el objeto que debo emplear para mapear ese objeto?
Ya probé con los siguiente:
public class objHelper
{
    public List<obj_A> listA { get; set; }
    public List<obj_B> listB { get; set; }
    public List<obj_C> listC { get; set; }
}

Estoy seteando el objeto de esta manera:
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var res = response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<objHelper>().Result;

}

Agradezco la ayuda...

primero, el json que te devuelve la API es exactamente igual que pusiste en la pregunta? Porque si es asi, el formato de json, no es correcto, deberia ser algo como esto:
{
[
          {
              "nombre_arrayA": [
                  {
                      "Key1": "value",
                      "Key2": "value"
                  },
                  {
                      "Key1": "value",
                      "Key2": "value"
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "nombre_arrayB": [
                  {
                      "Key3": "value",
                      "Key4": "value"
                  },
                  {
                      "Key3": "value",
                      "Key4": "value"
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "nombre_arrayC": [
                  {
                      "Key3": "value",
                      "Key4": "value"
                  },
                  {
                      "Key3": "value",
                      "Key4": "value"
                  }
              ]
          }
        ]
}

Segundo:
El objeto que estas usando para mapear el json deberia estar correcto, pero el nombre de las listas debe coincidir con los nombres de los arrays del JSON, al igual que los campos de cada clase deben coincidir con los nombres de los campos del json que estas recibiendo.
Deberia quedar algo asi:
   public class objHelper
{
    public List<obj_A> nombre_arrayA{ get; set; }
    public List<obj_B> nombre_arrayB { get; set; }
    public List<obj_C> nombre_arrayC { get; set; }
}

y por ultimo, esto ya es una recomendación basada en mi experiencia, si llegas tener problemas con la forma en la que estas transformando el json, te recomiendo probar la libreria
using Newtonsoft.Json;

para hacer las transformaciones a json y viceversa,
es bastante intuitiva de usar.

.net core ya tiene incluidas las herramientas necesarias para hacer todas las transformaciones de json, sin necesidad de una libreria de terceros...

Si, tienes razón, lo actualice para dejarlo como sugerencia en caso de tener problemas con la forma nativa de transformar.. gracias por la acotacion.
